# Using both scroll and touchevents on android (phonegap)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, touch

I'm building an app in phonegap. The app makes heavy use of javascript and has a content area that should be scrollable. However I also need to use the touchStart and touchEnd events.

The problem is that, unless you use e.preventDefault on touchMove/touchStart, you will get the touchStart event only once and never again after that (Not useful).
If you do e.preventDefault() on either of those two, native scrolling is disabled (on mobile devices).

How do I allow native scrolling while also listening to touchstart + touchend?

Failing that, could I simulate native scrolling (using touchmove?)? I've tried my hand at this myself, and the result of that was frankly terrible.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution that allows scrolling and swiping at the same time in Chrome for Android, to avoid irresponsive URL bar during swipe detection. Unfortunatelly, scrolling simulation doesn't help in my case, because that doesn't affect Chrome's URL bar. Have you figured out a solution yet?